# Multiple OracleAQ listeners in the same jms container in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-jms, oracle-aq

Is it possible to create multiple listeners (for different topics) within once defined jms container in spring?

Assume following configuration...

```
<bean id="jmsContainer" class="{container class here}">
...
</bean>
```

and

```
<bean id="messageListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter">
...
</bean>
```

Is it possible to have more than one messageListener* in jmsContainer?

If it is... Is it good pattern to do so or it is better idea to use as many containers as many listeners you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; you need a container for each listener. Even when using the namespace for convenience...

```
<jms:listener-container ...>
   <jms:listener .../>
   <jms:listener .../>
</jms:listener-container />
```

...you get a seperate container for each listener. The namespace is just a convenient way to set common attributes for each container.